# MySQL query w/index matching fewer WHERE column is faster than index matching all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Been spending several days profiling a wide variety of queries used by a distributed application of ours in a MySQL database. Our app potentially stores millions of records on client database servers and the queries can vary enough so that the design of the indexes isn't always clear or easy. A tiny bit of extra overhead on query write it acceptable if the lookup speed is fast enough.

I've managed to narrow down a few composite indexes that work very well for nearly all of our most common queries. There may be some columns in the below indexes I can weed out, but I need to run tests to be sure.

However, **my problem:** A certain query actually runs *faster* when it uses an index that contains fewer columns present in the conditions.

The table structure with current composite indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prism_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `epoch` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `world_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `block_id` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `block_subid` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_block_id` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_block_subid` mediumint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `epoch` (`epoch`),
  KEY `block` (`block_id`,`action_id`,`player_id`),
  KEY `location` (`world_id`,`x`,`z`,`y`,`epoch`,`action_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have eight common queries that I've been testing and they all show incredible performance improvement on a database with 50 million records. One query however, doesn't.

The following query returns *11088 rows in (9.77 sec)* and uses the `location` index

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id,
       epoch,
       action,
       player,
       world_id,
       x,
       y,
       z
FROM prism_data
INNER JOIN prism_players p ON p.player_id = prism_data.player_id
INNER JOIN prism_actions a ON a.action_id = prism_data.action_id
WHERE world_id =
    (SELECT w.world_id
     FROM prism_worlds w
     WHERE w.world = 'world')
  AND (a.action = 'world-edit')
  AND (prism_data.x BETWEEN -7220 AND -7020)
  AND (prism_data.y BETWEEN -22 AND 178)
  AND (prism_data.z BETWEEN -9002 AND -8802)
  AND prism_data.epoch >= 1392220467;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys  | key      | key_len | ref                            | rows   | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | ref    | PRIMARY,action | action   | 77      | const                          |      1 | Using where; Using index           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | prism_data | ref    | epoch,location | location | 4       | const                          | 660432 | Using index condition; Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | p          | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY  | 4       | minecraft.prism_data.player_id |      1 | NULL                               |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | w          | ref    | world          | world    | 767     | const                          |      1 | Using where; Using index           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+
```

If I remove the `world` condition, it would no longer match the `location` index and instead uses the `epoch` index. Amazingly, it returns *11088 rows in (0.31 sec)*

**9.77 sec versus 0.31 sec** is too much of a difference to ignore. I don't understand why I'm not seeing such a performance kill on my other queries using the `location` index too but more importantly I don't know what I can do to fix this.

Comment: If you remove `w.world = 'world'`, don't you get an error that a subquery returned more than one row?

Comment: Are you saying it returns the result set quicker when you are not using the sub query `(SELECT w.world_id FROM prism_worlds w WHERE w.world = 'world')`?

Comment: Why do you need a join here - `SELECT w.world_id FROM prism_worlds w WHERE w.world = 'world'`?

Comment: If I remove the entire `world_id = (subquery)`, the `location` index is no longer used and the query is faster. In previous SO threads, we determined that using the subquery for the world name was *way* faster than using a normal join and where condition for it

Comment: Even if I use `world_id = 1` and skip the subquery for profiling pursposes, the query still takes 10.28 sec

Comment: What if you use `world_id = 1` and add an index on `(world_id, epoch)`? That index would make more sense for this query.

Comment: I am not following your question after this statement: `If I remove the entire world_id = (subquery), the location index is no longer used and the query is faster.` - Forgive me, but this seems like am obvious statement: my query is quicker if I don't perform a subquery.

Comment: @AgRizzo It has nothing to do with the subquery. No matter how I design the world condition, even avoiding the subquery entirely with `world_id = 1`, it's slower because it's using the `location` index instead of the `epoch`

Comment: @ypercube Why would `world_id, epoch` be better for the query than `world_id, x, y, z, epoch`? All of those columns are used in the conditions.

Comment: The condition on `x,y,z,epoch` are all range conditions so only of the first of them (in the index) is going to be used. Whether a `(world_id,x)` or `(world_id,y)` or `(world_id,z)` or `(world_id,epoch)` will be best depends on the selectivity, so the actual data you have and the parameters in each individual execution of the query.

Comment: Adding the rest of the columns (needed in WHERE and SELECT) of course will help reduce the time as well - by getting all the data for the 10k returned rows from the index and not hitting the base table. But still whether `(world_id,x,...)` or `(world_id,y,...)` or `(world_id,z,...)` or `(world_id,epoch,...)` will be the best, depends on your data and parameters.

Comment: I suggested `(world_id, epoch, ...)` because it seems that `epoch` has good selectivity.

Comment: @ypercube Ok thanks. The epoch is used in roughly 70% of all queries so I'll try to alter the order of the columns in the index or try a separate index. I'll report back with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the "epoch" index is more selective than the "location" index.

Note that MySQL might be running the subquery once for every row.  That could have considerable overhead, even with an index.  Doing 30 million index lookups might take a little time.

Try doing the query this way:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id,
       epoch,
       action,
       player,
       world_id,
       x,
       y,
       z
FROM prism_data
INNER JOIN prism_players p ON p.player_id = prism_data.player_id
INNER JOIN prism_actions a ON a.action_id = prism_data.action_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT w.world_id FROM prism_worlds w WHERE w.world = 'world') w
WHERE world_id = w.world_id
  AND (a.action = 'world-edit')
  AND (prism_data.x BETWEEN -7220 AND -7020)
  AND (prism_data.y BETWEEN -22 AND 178)
  AND (prism_data.z BETWEEN -9002 AND -8802)
  AND prism_data.epoch >= 1392220467;
```

If this doesn't show an improvement, then the issue is selectivity of the indexes.  MySQL is simply making the wrong decision on which is the best index to use.  If this does show an improvement, then it is because the subquery is being executed only one time in the `from` clause.

EDIT:

Your location index is:

```
KEY `location` (`world_id`,`x`,`z`,`y`,`epoch`,`action_id`)
```

Can you change this to:

```
KEY `location` (`world_id`, action_id  `x`, `z`, `y`, `epoch`)
```

This allows the `where` filtering to use the `action_id` as well as `x`.  (Only the first inequality uses direct index lookups.)

or better yet, one of of these:

```
KEY `location` (`world_id`, action_id, epoch, `x`, `z`, `y`)
KEY `location` (`world_id`, epoch, action_id, `x`, `z`, `y`)
KEY `location` (epoch, `world_id`, action_id, `x`, `z`, `y`)
```

The idea is to move `epoch` before `x` so it will be used for the `where` clause conditions.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Just for informational value, the world subquery was the most efficient suggestion in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763950/improving-mysql-index-efficiency-columns-in-multiple-indexes

Comment: This query format shows no improvement unfortunately, 9.71 sec

Comment: Then it is an issue of the epoch index being the better index.  Try adding the `use index (epoch)` to the query.

Comment: If this works, it will be tricky to implement. Our application allows users to search for data using a variety of condition so the queries often vary as to what columns they include. I'd have to add logic to the app to determine when the `use index` is needed. So far, it seems to be only for this case, all the other queries work alright.

Comment: Forcing the index on the original slow query helped though, so that's a possible solution.